# jest X is not a function inside module from node modules

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

My test is failing with

```
● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                  
    TypeError: debug is not a function

      at newDebug (../node_modules/fetch-mock/cjs/lib/debug.js:9:5)
```

In my jest.config.js i have:

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    '../node_modules/(?!(fetch-mock)/.*)',
    '<rootDir>/../node_modules/(?!(fetch-mock)/.*)',
    '<rootDir>/../node_modules/(?!(fetch-mock))',
    '<rootDir>/../node_modules/(?!fetch-mock/)',
    'node_modules/(?!fetch-mock/)',
  ],
```

But nothing seems to work.
Please help!